# Scala multiple inheritence with Classes

Tags: scala, oop

Why Scala doesn't support Multiple Inheritance with ordinary classes? can't we apply the same linearization logic we apply to Traits incase of classes too? This should be possible since it is how multiple inheritance (with normal classes) is implemented in Python via C3 Linearization.

Comment: [scala-debate] or one of the other Scala mailing lists would be a better place for this question, but in short the answer's going to be something like "JVM / Java compatibility".

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/237118/43961

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about Python, but IMO, the difference between a trait and a class is the constructor.

A constructor have many limitations as compared to a normal method. For example, they can only be called once per object, they have to be called for each new object, and a child class constructor must call it's parent's constructor.

```
                       A
                     /   \    
                    /     \
                   B       C
                    \     /
                     \   /
                       D
```

Now, the famous diamond problem. If B and C inherits from A and D inherits from B and C, then the constructor of A will be called twice. Unlike choosing the implementation of methods of traits, constructors of both B and C have to be called which in turn needs to call constructor of A.

Traits avoid this problem since they don't have constructors.

Comment: This is a nice answer ;)

Comment: Martin Odersky said that Scala doesn't need classes. He has a sketch for a sane initialization ordering algorithm and a sketch for a proof of correctness for that algorithm. Classes are purely for compatibility with the underlying host platform(s).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Interesting. Can you please cite the source. Its weird though if Martin Odersky said that considering the scala collection library's source code has classes everywhere and Martin is author of most of those files.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm a bit late to the party, but I too would be curious :)

Answer (score 1):

Scala doesn't need classes at all. You could just have traits have constructors, and be done with it.

The only reason it has classes, is for compatibility with the underlying host platform. And most of the platforms Scala wants to run on (Java, .NET, Objective-C/Cocoa, ECMAScript) only support single inheritance for classes (or prototypes in ECMAScript).